# Simplify: Why does it miss this simple one?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I got a result with the expression

```
((x2^2 - 2*x2*x3 + x3^2 + y2^2 - 2*y2*y3 + y3^2)*
       (x1^4 - 2*x1^3*x2 + x1^2*x2^2 - 2*x1^3*x3 + 4*x1^2*x2*x3 - 
          2*x1*x2^2*x3 + x1^2*x3^2 - 2*x1*x2*x3^2 + x2^2*x3^2 + 
    2*x1^2*y1^2 - 
          2*x1*x2*y1^2 + x2^2*y1^2 - 2*x1*x3*y1^2 + x3^2*y1^2 + y1^4 - 
          2*x1^2*y1*y2 + 4*x1*x3*y1*y2 - 2*x3^2*y1*y2 - 2*y1^3*y2 + 
    x1^2*y2^2 - 
          2*x1*x3*y2^2 + x3^2*y2^2 + y1^2*y2^2 - 2*x1^2*y1*y3 + 
    4*x1*x2*y1*y3 - 
          2*x2^2*y1*y3 - 2*y1^3*y3 + 4*y1^2*y2*y3 - 2*y1*y2^2*y3 + 
    x1^2*y3^2 - 
          2*x1*x2*y3^2 + x2^2*y3^2 + y1^2*y3^2 - 2*y1*y2*y3^2 + 
    y2^2*y3^2))
```

in the nuerator of something else. (It all was part of a rule and the numerator also had a denominator).

This expression can easily be simplified further. I wonder, why it did not try to apply Simplify to the right hand side of the rule. Especially in this case in question here, applying Simplify to the expression yields

```
(x1^2 - 2*x1*x2 + x2^2 + (y1 - y2)^2)*(x1^2 - 2*x1*x3 + x3^2 + (y1 - y3)^2)*
 (x2^2 - 2*x2*x3 + x3^2 + (y2 - y3)^2)
```

Everyone eaasily sees that (x1-x2)^2, (x1-x3)^2 and (x2-x3)^2 appear in this result without being factored. **Strangely if recognizes that the yi-differences can be factored but not the xi-Differences. Why that?**

How could I direct Simplify to factor such simple subexpressions where applicable?

Can I direct Mathematica to apply Simplify separately to all right hand sides of an expression or is this always done automaticly?

Comment: FullSimplify does it for both x's and y's. May be it is just a case of Simplify stopping at a particular point, having a found a simpler expression than the one provided.

Comment: `Simplify[]` is not automatically applied by default, since a. it can take a while for sufficiently complicated inputs; and b. one might not want to simplify a result for a given application. I would be annoyed if the software converted `x^3 + 3 x^2 + 3 x + 1` or `(x - 1) (x^2 + x + 1)` into their simpler forms without me asking it to do so.